# how to Call Function after Page Load completed

Tags: php

I am trying to call a function after the page has been sent to the browser, but I haven't found a way to do so.

I have tried both register_shutdown_function and __destruct but it does not work.

This is the structure I have:

```
register_shutdown_function('MyClass::Save');
MyClass::Initialize();
CreateAllOutput();
```

MyClass::Save has a sleep(20) inside.

The shutdown function gets called after the CreateAllOutput(), but the truth is that the loading bar on the browser only finishes after the Save function has been executed, waiting 20 seconds... I tried the same using a non static class and __destruct having a sleep(20) inside, and the same happens.

Is there a way of getting the function to only be executed after the output has all been sent to the browser?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generally: **no**. There is no possibility except to flush all output and then call it, but the loading bar in the browser won't finish either.

The only thing I can think of is putting an iFrame into the page to call a PHP file with the save function. Or you could make an Ajax call.

A third possibility would be to call `exec()` (**[Documentation](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php)**). After making a php file executeable you can run it with that method. As mentioned in the documentation:

> If a program is started with this
>   function, in order for it to continue
>   running in the background, the output
>   of the program must be redirected to a
>   file or another output stream. Failing
>   to do so will cause PHP to hang until
>   the execution of the program ends.

Comment: I actually didn't require such feature until now, but this seems a major limitation. I just wanted a function to be ran without the user being forced to wait for it, as they will be expecting the page to finish loading, just to see that nothing was added to the output... Disappointing...

Comment: @BlunT - i have added another possible solution in my answer

Comment: I already thought of doing exec, but it just seems too much overhead, and I am not even sure I am able to that that, since I am on a shared hosting environment. I was hoping for a simple and straight solution that I might have missed from google, but so far does not seem so.

Comment: @BlunT sorry but there is no other solution