# get table cell value using php only no ajax

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

```
var $rows = $('#tableid').find("tr:not(:eq(0))");
var valueToPush1 = [];
$rows.each(function() {
    var $tds = $(this).find('td');
    var id = $tds.eq(0).text();
    var address = $tds.eq(1).text();
    var school = $tds.eq(2).text();
    var firstname = $tds.eq(3).find('#fname').html();
    var minitial = $tds.eq(3).find('#minitial').html();
    var lastname = $tds.eq(3).find('#lname').html();
    valueToPush1.push({
        id: id,
        address: address,
        school: school,
        firstname: firstname,
        middleinitial: minitial,
        lastname: lastname

    });
});
```

I can get table cell value in js using this code how can i convert this code so i can get the value in php side directly and not using ajax. Is this even possible?

Comment: Why? Why not just get the values client side using built-in DOM APIs (and jQuery) instead of haggling with it server-side?

Comment: i can get it using jquery as i have said in the question. My problem lies with another operation in my project i cant send a file in ajax to php but i can do it directly in php so i will try to just get the value of table directly using php instead of using ajax..this is another solution i am thinking to complete my project

Comment: some help: http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php http://php.net/manual/en/domdocument.loadhtml.php

Comment: Php runs once then it's done, you can't use php to manipulate the DOM, at least not without using Ajax

Comment: @DelightedD0D i just want to save the file together with the table cell value in data is this not feasible?

Comment: @HogRider. The real question is how your data (table) generated. The table you are talking about is generated by same project or using some third party tool or data?

Comment: @SD. same project i get the data for the table in the database it is generated dynamically

Comment: @HogRider Then why don't you use same method to get the value again? As, once data is sent to browser there are two ways to sent those data back to server 1) using HTML form and 2) using Javascritp AJAX.

Comment: @SD. currently i am using ajax i am successful in sending the table value as stated above in the question my dilemma is in the file(pdf) i cant send it properly in the php using ajax but if i get the file(pdf) directly from php i am successful so i was thinking if i could get the table cell value directly in php then it will work out fine

Comment: This seems like an X Y Problem (see http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem ) Can you walk us through what you actually need step by step, rather than explaining what you are trying now. That is to say, please explain what you need to accomplish rather than asking how to make your solution work. I bet if we get to the actual problem, there's a better way to solve it altogether. There shouldnt be any reason you can't use ajax for this, not seemingly anyway.

Answer (score -1):

I have an idea, there are 2 steps.

1. Create a hidden input that retrieve the value so the value can be passed from php to javascript or from javascript to php. If from javascript to php, make sure you load the value onloaded document/page.
2. Then make a php public variable, then do the mysql insert query.

For technically, first please do by one by one step.

Comment: Can you clarify what mean here. How exactly are you going to run the `php`  code to "do the mysql insert query" after the page loads without using ajax?

Comment: Store the value into a hidden input first, then with onChange for that hidden input so the value sould passed into a javascript variable.

Comment: Ok, but after that....How exactly are you going to run the php code to "do the mysql insert query" after the page loads without using ajax? To my knowledge that is not possible to do. There is no way to invoke a `php` function after the page loads, aside from using ajax to call a `php` script in another file of course.  There are dozens of questions about this on SO. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6625424/how-to-call-function-after-page-load-completed for example. Bottom line, this wont work without ajax.